# Change div's height from top

Tags: jquery, html, css

By using jquery, I want to cut a square height from top. It seems that by default it does it from bottom. How can I change that?

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4wcspy1/

```
<style>
.square {
height:100px;
width: 100px;
background:black;
position:absolute;

}
</style>
<body>
<div class="square"></div>
<script>
$('div').click(function(){
$(this).css('height','60px')})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you change the margin top    

$(this).css('margin-top','40px');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the js:

```
 $('div').click(function(){
         $init = $(this).height(); 
         $slice = 60;
        $(this).css({'height':$slice+'px',
                     'margin-top':$init-$slice +'px'
                    })

    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9n29ex0o/1/

Comment: Something wrong in code when I click again it go up again

Comment: the $init variable has changed and the margin will eq to 0

Answer (score 0):

I have done this please use below code in js

```
$('div').click(function(){
            $(this).css({"height":"60px","margin-top":"40px"})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
.square {
height:100px;
width: 100px;
background:black;
position:absolute;

}
</style>
<body>
<div class="square"></div>
<script>
$('div').click(function(){
$(this).height("60");})
</script>
</body>
</html>



**$(this).height("60");**
```

It's jQuery's function.
You can get more info from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_height.asp)